# C++ same template used for more than 1 function?

Tags: c++, function, templates

How can I modify the below code so that I could use the same template T even in call() function?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
void swap(T &x,T &y)
{
 T temp=x;
 x=y;
 y=temp;
}

/*if i use again the"template<class T>" here i have the error "Identifier T is 
undefined" to be gone but then if i compile i have several other errors.. like  
"could be 'void swap<T>(T &,T &)' " and some other errors*/

void call(T &x,T &y)
{
 swap(x,y);
 cout<<x<<y;
}

int main()
{
 int num;
 cout<<"Enter 1 or 0 for int or float\n";
 cin>>num;
 if(num)
 {
  int a,b;
  cin>>a>>b;
  call(a,b);
 }
 else 
 {
  float a,b;
  cin>>a>>b;
  call(a,b);
 }
}
```

A template function is associated with the template declaration at the start. Can't the same template be used again for another function? Is there an other way to modify the above code so that I could use the same or any other template in call() function? Overall I need to manage all functions using templates itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
void call(T &x, T &y)
{
   swap(x, y);
   cout << x<< y;
}
```

should work.

The problem is probably because you have `using namespace std;` and there already exists `std::swap`, so it's ambiguous.

Comment: no, that's not my question.. i didnt find any wrong with declaring template<typename T> above call().. but then if i compile i get errors.. so where am i doing the mistake? and what it has to do with std::swap.. pleasee explain??

Comment: @bkpro do you still get errors if you remove the `using namespace std;`? (after changing `cin` and `cout` to `std::cin` and `std::cout`) It means that there are two methods called `swap` - the one you define, and the one in `std::`.

Comment: @bkpro I told you how to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your #include is bringing in the standard library std::swap template. Because you use "using namespace std" the compiler can't tell which function you want to call, your or the one in the standard library.

You have two choices, either stop using "using namespace std" or be explicit about which swap function you want to call, so in your call function write "::swap(x, y)" instead.

(Note that you DO need to put "template " in the defintion of your call function)

Comment: so if i put std::swap(x,y) the ambiguity is removed about which function to call(either one i defined or in the namespace).. and btw i compulsorily need to include the template definition again above the second function.. no other go right?

Comment: Yes you can always explicity say which namespace your function is in. So in this case std::swap chooses the one in "std" and ::swap chooses the one in the global namespace that you defined. (This is also a good reason for always putting your code in your own namespace - so you can have the convenience of "using namespace" but still let you resolve conflicts if they occur.)

Comment: yess.. i understand the importance of namespace.. 
But why the compiler simple not associate the call() function to the earlier defined template at the top.. y do i have it declare it again above the call() function.. Any reason??

Answer (score -1):

you may define a typdef or macro to make it smaller. But it is recommended to put template definitions because it makes the code readable. Also you can encapsulate two functions in a class which is a template.

```
template<class T>
class XYZ {

void swap(T &x,T &y)
{
 T temp=x;
 x=y;
 y=temp;
}

void call(T &x,T &y)
{
 swap(x,y);
 cout<<x<<y;
}
}
```

or something like this if you don't want to use classes also you don't want to use `template<class T>` :

```
#define templateFor(T) template<class T>

templateFor(T)
void swap(T &x,T &y)
{
 T temp=x;
 x=y;
 y=temp;
}


templateFor(T)
void call(T &x,T &y)
{
 swap(x,y);
 cout<<x<<y;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to call the functions through an instance of a class?

Comment: He wants to not mention template directive for second function. Making a class and pushing all functions is it can be a solution for this question. But I agree it is not engineered very well.

Comment: This doesn't actually solve anything, and please don't do this. This macro gives absolutely no advantage over `template<class T>`.

Comment: Also this post doesn't solve anything. The owner just doesn't want to write the second template directive. I'm totally agree with you and I accept the negative response.

Comment: @tenfour Just realize some keyboards are quite brittle and need to be replaced if some keys wear out. Templates emphasize the use of the `<` and `>` keys, so this may significantly affect keyboard lifetime. The problem is further compounded by the fact that the [preprocessor doesn't support a trigraph alternative for `<>`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C).

Comment: ... To combat excessive keyboard wear, I've changed my keyboard layout on occasion, mapping the `q` and `x` keys to `<` and `>` in the past. On other consoles, you can always use Alt+60, Alt+62 (windows). Macros should be a last resort, indeed.

Comment: @sehe: I'm hoping someone can do the math to see exactly how cost-effective the macro is.