# Using macros to generate a class at compile time

Tags: c++, macros

Is it possible to construct the class below using macros?

```
struct ModelName
{
public:
    typedef std::string type;

    static type get( const GameObject* obj )
    {
        return obj->getAttribute< type >( MODEL_NAME );
    }
};
```

In other words, I would like to generate the above code at compile time given the three parameters: `ModelName`, `MODEL_NAME`, and `std::string`. Is that possible?

EDIT: After typing it out, I realized I can achieve what I want using templates. For some reason I thought it wouldn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use a template?

Comment: Why don't you use a template instead of a macro?

Comment: Perhaps a template would work </band wagon>

Comment: If enough peple told you, would you use a template?

Comment: I think no-one has mentioned the obvious solution yet: use a template.

Comment: Strange that nobody recommended using a template...

Comment: If I randomly add the word template to my first comment, will it get upvoted?

Comment: Templates would be nice, but your keyboard would _have to_ support the `'<'` and `'>'` characters...

Comment: @sehe, But then you'd have to use a digraph in order to use a digraph for { and } and [ and ].

Comment: I dunno guys the template way could be difficult if `MODEL_NAME` is an overloaded function.

Comment: A little side note: No macros are there at compile time.

Comment: @chris I addressed the issue of trigraphs for `<` and `>` and excessive keyboard wear at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314737/c-same-template-used-for-more-than-1-function/12314780#comment16525643_12314780

Comment: @sehe, Nice one. You found that pretty quickly.

Comment: Sorry guys :( I wasn't thinking this through.

Answer (score 4):

Sure:

```
#define DEFINE_ATTRIBUTE(classname, attributeName, attributeType)   \
        struct classname                                            \
        {                                                           \
            typedef attributeType type;                             \
                                                                    \
            static type get(const GameObject* const obj)            \
            {                                                       \
                return obj->getAttribute<type>(attributeName);      \
            }                                                       \
        }
```

(The missing semicolon is normal; it forces/allows the use of a semicolon after the macro.)

You may consider redesigning this as a template, if possible.

Comment: If we *have* to use a macro, especially a multi-line macro, it may be better to wrap it inside a `do { ... } while( 0 )` construct.

Comment: @ArunSaha: That just flat out doesn't make sense here. Unless your goal is to define each of these in its own scope, within a function, never to be seen again.